Show that a map $\Omega(M) \rightarrow \tilde \Omega$ induced by $\pi^*$ is a bijection.
This question is from an old publicly available qualifying exam that I’m using to learn this field (Stanford geometry and topology). All work is my own.


Let $M$ and $N$ be smooth, connected manifolds and let $\pi: M \times N \rightarrow M$ be the standard projection. A tangent vector $V$ to $M \times N$ is called vertical if $\pi_* V = 0$. For any $p$-form on $M \times N$ we define the $(p-1)$-form $\iota_V \omega$ by $$ (\iota_V \omega)(x_1 , \dots , x_{p-1}) = \omega(V, x_1, \dots, x_{p-1})$$ Consider $$ \tilde \Omega =  \{ \omega \in \Omega^* (M \times N) \mid \iota_V \omega  = 0    \text{ and } \iota_V(d \omega) = 0 \text{ for all vertical vectors } V\}.$$ Show that a map $\Omega(M) \rightarrow \tilde \Omega$ induced by $\pi^*$ is a bijection.

Answer: For convenience, let's label our map as $f: \Omega(M) \rightarrow \tilde \Omega$.
We'll first prove injectivity.
We know from here that the map induced by $\pi^*$ behaves idempotently on any forms in the image of $\pi$. Then
$$ 0 = \pi^* \sum \alpha_i dx_i = \sum \alpha_i dx_i = 0 \iff (\forall i)  ,  \alpha_i = 0$$
Thus $\ker f = 0$. As an additional consequence, we have that $$ \text{dim }\text{img }f = \text{dim } \Omega(M)$$
Next we'll prove surjectivity. If we can prove that the dimension of $\tilde \Omega$ is the same as $\Omega(M)$, then the injectivity of our linear map will imply surjectivity. Claim incorrectly that there is some form $\sum \alpha_j dx_j \in \sim \Omega$ that has a higher dimension then a pullback of $\pi^*$, but still projects down to $\Omega(M)$. Then there is some component $\alpha_j dx_j$ with a dual component $\alpha_j ex_j$ that is vertical. But if it our form were to have a vertical dualized component, and our form's dualization were to project down to a nonzero value of $\Omega(M)$, then $$\left( \sum \alpha_j dx_j \right)(V, \dots) \neq 0$$ which is absurd. Thus the forms in $\tilde \Omega$ have to have the same dimension as those of $\text{img }f$. This proves our map is surjective.
Because the map is both injective and surjective, it is clearly a bijection.

(a) Are the injective and surjective cases correct?
As a bonus, if there's a more powerful technique, concept, or theorem that allows a more economical solution, then please let me know.
